# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given using laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to show array dates in check-in variable from the controller but unfortunately,
I am getting error please help me how can resolve that thanks.

Please check the error here

https://flareapp.io/share/dmkyk4l7

**return $dates**

```
[
  "01-10-2021",
  "02-10-2021",
  "03-10-2021",
  "04-10-2021"
]
```

**jquery script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let checkInn = "{{ $dates }}";
    // var checkInn = ["10-10-2021", "10-10-2021"];
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if (checkInn.indexOf(dmy) != -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In php, you have to json_encode() your $dates array, than use htmlspecialchars() on string you get. Guess in script you than have to use `let checkInn = {{ $dates }};`, which will generate a Javascript array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one , you need to use  @json()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     
       let checkInn =  @json($array);
      // var checkInn = ["10-10-2021","10-10-2021"];
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
          format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
          beforeShowDay: function(date){
              dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
              if(checkInn.indexOf(dmy) != -1){
                  return false;
              }
              else{
                  return true;
              }
          }
      });
    </script>
```